# Selenium [Javascript Application] Error

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       // driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

The InternetExplorerDriver works fine (with the .exe), but with the Firefox driver, I get an apparent JavaScript error, any ideas what I am missing that causes this popup?  The test will technically work for a few seconds as long as I click ok on each popup, but the test soon fails and exits.

The popup (can't post picture) 
Title: [JavaScript Application]
Message: Error: syntax error
Button: OK

I have tried playing around with the different options for the FireFoxProfile and FirefoxBinary but that didn't seem to be the right direction either.  I wasn't sure if the newest version of firefox was causing the problem (17) or if I needed the exe file specifically in the solution like the IEdriver.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a separate driver for firefox as is the case for IE and chrome.
though I have found quite a few posts with the same error as yours on net..so seems to be an issue with the 17 version.  You can either downgrade ur ff version or have a look at the options in the below threads (Disclaimer : I havent tried the below :) )

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/944619

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942417

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of Selenium? I am assuming you are using WebDriver? The current version is 2.28.0 [Selenium Downloads](http://seleniumhq.org/download/.)

Comment: I have the current version of Selenium and have used Firefox 17 and 18.  I am going to try to find a VM with an older Firefox, about 12.  If it doesn't work there, then I know its something else.

Comment: Firefox 17 works very well with 2.28 the only problem I have been having with it is that it ignores my implicit timeouts. Other than that it works wonderfully. What are you trying to do with your test?

Comment: I was trying to get a faster version of my test (I started with IE).  I still get a javascript popup dialog on every page my test makes it to using Firefox.  I switched to Chrome and have been happy with the results so far as it is night and day faster than IE.